# Failed at the tekbook@0.1.0 start script 'node server.js'

Tags: node.js

I have problems with node and npm packages.

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-86-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! tekbook@0.1.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the tekbook@0.1.0 start script 'node server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the tekbook package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs tekbook
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls tekbook
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/nodejs/TekBook/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: npm start not working

Comment: Please delete your `node_modules` and `npm install` again.  Also what version of Node / NPM are you using?

Comment: Yes working.. Its correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Update your Node js to latest version
2. Delete your **node_modules** and **npm install**